# CKeditor JQuery Adapter error

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm having problem with CKEditor's jquery adapter. I've included jquery, editor and adapter and when I call

```
$('textarea').ckeditor();
```

it says `ckeditor` is not a function. I've checked included files, `CKEDITOR.replace` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you aren't loading jQuery correctly. If you do, that code will work fine. Can you post a test page?